# is it possible to get undecoded base64 attachment data in javax.mail MimeMessageParser

Tags: base64, encode, jakarta-mail

I am parsing attachments using MimeMessageParser/DataSource classes from javax.mail.  The incoming MIME has base64 encoded attachment files, and I need the base64 encoded output as is, but DataSource.getInputStream() returns decoded output.  As I have to store the base64 in my application, I don't want re-encode it again to base64, if possible.  Please let me know if there is a way.

```
MimeMessageParser mmparser;
mmparser=....
..
for (int i = 0; i < attachmentList.size(); i++) {
DataSource dataSource = attachmentList.get(i);
//dataSource.getInputStream(); this returns decoded stream
// need the base64 encoded stream fromm the original email attachment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you drop using the MimeMessageParser in favor of using the JavaMail API directly you can use the [MimeBodyPart.getRawInputStream](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#getRawInputStream--) to extract the encoded data.